# Undefined index: debuging error for theme option template snippet

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, debug, deprecation

Hello I tried to find the solution but couldn't get what I am looking for..I am getting error exactly as bellow..

Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-content\themes\mytheme\admin\admin-panel.php on line 745

and code on line 745 is

```
function mytheme_add_init() {

$file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
wp_enqueue_style("functions", $file_dir."/admin/functions.css", false, "1.0", "all");
wp_enqueue_script("rm_script", $file_dir."/admin/rm_script.js", false, "1.0");

}
```

I dont know if I am using deprecated snippet or so.

Comment: Please provide us the *entire* source of your `admin-panel.php` file, or at least more code surrounding this line.  There isn't anything in the code snippet you posted that's even using an index ...

Comment: here is my admin-panel.php
http://snipt.org/kgnlg6

Its too long and will goon for more options.. I would appreciate your help.. Thanks a lot

Also kindly know me the mistake to learn..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your actual source, the relevant portion (with line numbers) is this:

```
745 if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
746 
747     if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
748
749         foreach ($options as $value) {
750             update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }
751
752         foreach ($options as $value) {
753             if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }
754
755     header("Location: admin.php?page=admin-panel.php&saved=true");
756     die;
757
758 }
```

You're checking for "page" inside the global `$_GET` variable, but in this case, it's not set.  You need to run an `isset()` check first.

```
745 if ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
```

This will first check to see if we've passed in a value for 'page' in the request.  If not, then we move on.  If we have passed one in, though, then we'll compare it to `basename(__FILE__)` as normal.

You should use this same `isset()` pattern with `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` variables as well, otherwise you'll get the same notices.

Comment: I have modified code as per your direction and error gone for my admin panel but for front end error still remains the same

Here is my modified admin-panel.php
http://snipt.org/kww9

Front end error message is "
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\pixelngrain\wp-content\themes\Pixel_n_Grain\header.php on line 10" and its not only for header but for all where I am using this code plus variable to get theme options..

also adding header.php to see if I am wrong anywhere.
http://snipt.org/kwG0

for your information I am not familiar much with php and still learning yet.

Comment: Look at line 10 in header.php.  You're calling `get_settings( $value['id'] )` but aren't first checking that "id" is set in the `$value` array.  It's the exact same problem you had before.  You need to check to see if "id" is set first.  Change your if statement from `if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE)` to `if ( isset( $value['id'])  && get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks for reply EAMann, I have tried and modified below code but still same error exists

`<?php
   global $options;
   foreach ($options as $value) {
   if ( isset( $value['id']) && get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }
   }
  ?>`

Comment: The exact same error?  Or just an "undefined index" warning?  If you changed the code in such a way, then that particular "undefined index" warning for header.php would disappear.

Comment: Error is the same for header.php line 10..  " Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\pixelngrain\wp-content\themes\Pixel_n_Grain\header.php on line 10" Also same error I am getting whenever I am using above code to get theme option. I have notice if I am removing php from <?php than error just disappear but I believe this is a bad solution even for <?php echo $png_title; ?> also needs to remove php.. So I am very confused what is the reason.

Comment: Without seeing your full code and the full text of every warning (and these are warnings, not errors), I can't be more precise.  The advice I've already given is the standard pattern for fixing this warning ... so there must be something else going on or some other code missing, but I can't tell for sure because I can't see it.

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: std in C:\xampp\htdocs\pixelngrain\wp-content\themes\Pixel_n_Grain\header.php on line 10"

"Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\pixelngrain\wp-content\themes\Pixel_n_Grain\header.php on line 10"

Above are exactly error message what I am getting on front end. Same thing I am getting for other pages too where I am using theme option code

I have already attached my admin-panel.php and header.php in above post. Please let me know if you need anything more specific.

Comment: The `undefined index: std` is because you're calling `$value['std']` without first checking if it's set.  Ultimately, you need a check before you run any of this code to make sure that `$value` is the type of array/object that you expect. These warnings are meant to tell you that you're trying to access values and properties that don't exist. Don't just assume that they're there, *check first* then run the rest of your application logic.

Comment: Okay now I able to rid of all those error but pops up another error :( .. Notice: get_settings is deprecated since version 2.1! Use get_option() instead. in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pixelngrain\\wp-includes\\functions.php on line 3382 Posts

I am getting this error at many areas..as per my knowledge I have changed all get_settings to get_option now how to find which are still remain?
I really appreciate your effort and help and hope you are not getting frustrate with me.